# Property 'origin' not found on object type 'UITextField'

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to scroll my text box up when the keyboard appears on the iPhone, I am using the following code but I get the error:

> Property 'origin' not found on object type 'UITextField'

```
studentLoanTextBox.frame = CGRectMake(
    studentLoanTextBox.origin.x, 
    studentLoanTextBox.origin.y - 100.0, 
    studentLoanTextBox.frame.size.width, 
    studentLoanTextBox.frame.size.height
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`origin` is a member of `CGRect`, you have to get a `CGRect` from you view. Have a look at the `frame` property of `UIView`.

Change all occurences of `studentLoanTextBox.origin` to `studentLoanTextBox.frame.origin`